# Option getOrElse type mismatch error

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, type-mismatch

Why does this code raise a type mismatch error in Scala 2.9.2? I expected that `getOrElse` returns type `String` but actually it returns `java.io.Serializable`:

```
scala> implicit def StringToOption(s:String) = Option(s)
StringToOption: (s: String)Option[String]

scala> "a".getOrElse("")
res0: String = a

scala> var opt:Option[String] = "a".getOrElse("")
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.io.Serializable
 required: Option[String]
       var opt:Option[String] = "a".getOrElse("")
                                             ^
```

This is OK:

```
scala> implicit def StringToOption(s:String): Option[String] = Option(s)
StringToOption: (s: String)Option[String]

scala> var b:Option[String] = "a".getOrElse("") toString
b: Option[String] = Some(a)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's an unwanted case of incomplete tree traversal.  The signature of `getOrElse` allows type widening, so when it realizes that `String` is not `Option[String]` it first tries to fill in a different type ascription on `getOrElse`, i.e. `Serializable`.  But now it has `"a".getOrElse[Serializable]("")` and it's stuck--it doesn't realize, I guess, that the problem was making the type too general before checking for implicits.

Once you realize the problem, there's a fix:

```
"a".getOrElse[String]("")
```

Now the typer doesn't wander down the let's-widen path, and finds the implicit.