# Error while converting nullable java Boolean to scala Boolean

Tags: java, scala

Trying to read an Optional/Nullable java boolean into scala boolean.

I am getting error while using following approach:

> ```
> val nullableJavaBool: java.lang.Boolean = java.lang.Boolean.TRUE
> val x: scala.Boolean = Option(nullableJavaBool).getOrElse(java.lang.Boolean.FALSE)
> val y: scala.Boolean = Option(nullableJavaBool).getOrElse(false)
> ```
>
> [scalac-2.11]
> /myworkspace/MyClass.scala:43:
> error: type mismatch; [scalac-2.11]  found   : Any [scalac-2.11]
> required: Boolean [scalac-2.11]     val x: scala.Boolean =
> Option(nullableJavaBool).getOrElse(java.lang.Boolean.FALSE)
> [scalac-2.11]
> ^ [scalac-2.11]
>
> /myworkspace/MyClass.scala:43:
> error: type mismatch; [scalac-2.11]  found   : Any [scalac-2.11]
> required: Boolean [scalac-2.11]     val y: scala.Boolean =
> Option(nullableJavaBool).getOrElse(false)

Could you please explain the reason behind this error and what is better way to achieve this?

Comment: @STaefi, no looks like different question.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the type-inferencer that scala uses. The problem is that type inferencer sometimes could not infer supertype of a higher-kinded type like Option[T], although it is obvious to the user what it is.
It is not as much problem with boolean as much as with the Option, consider this answer for the full problem explanation:

[Option getOrElse type mismatch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186063/option-getorelse-type-mismatch-error)

To correct your code you'll have to put some types by hand:

```
val nullableJavaBool: java.lang.Boolean = java.lang.Boolean.TRUE
val x:scala.Boolean = (Option(nullableJavaBool).getOrElse[java.lang.Boolean](java.lang.Boolean.FALSE))
```

BTW your approach for converting boolean values is OK, although simple `if b == null then ... else ...` will use less resources